# UIScrollviews zoomToRect only sets the zoomScale but not the contentOffset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

My `UIScrollView` is not setting its `contentOffset` when using `zoomToRect`.

I have an `UIScrollView` with an `UIImageView` inside. Scrolling and zooming itself is working so far. Now I want to give the scrollview at app start a certain zoomed rect of the image view. For this I implemented `zoomToRect:` and it is setting the `zoomsScale` correctly, but it does not set the `contentOffset`.

Expected outcome when using `zoomToRect` is that the `UIScrollView` zooms in or out according to the selected rect and set its `contentOffset` according to the origin coordinates of the rect given to the `zoomToRect` method.
The actual behaviour is that it zooms to the correct `zoomScale` but my `UIImageView` is always at the origin 0,0 and not the expected origin of the x (475) and y (520) coordinated of the rect I specified in `zoomToRect`.
My images size is 1473x1473.

Here is some the code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGRect bounds = self.view.frame;

    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"]];

    self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    _containerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    _scrollView.delegate = self;
    _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.bounds.size;
    _scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
    [_scrollView addSubview:_containerView];

    [_containerView addSubview:_imageView];

    [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [_scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(475.0, 150.0, 520.0, 747.0) animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return _containerView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    [self printVisibleRectToConsole:scrollView];

    CGSize newImageViewSizeWithScale = CGSizeMake(_imageView.bounds.size.width * _scrollView.zoomScale,
                                 _imageView.bounds.size.height * _scrollView.zoomScale);
    _scrollView.contentSize = newImageViewSizeWithScale;
}
```

My questions:

- Why does `zoomToRect` does not set the `contentOffset`?
- How can I get `zoomToRect` to change my `contentOffset` as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the view you're zooming (`containerView`) is not as big as the image view it contains (and which you actually want to zoom). Its `frame` is set to the `frame` of the view controller. You don't see this because a `UIView` doesn't clip its subviews by default.

You should initialize `containerView` with the bounds of your image view instead.

```
self.containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_imageView.bounds];
```